# Why running in GDB changes function return?

Tags: c++, gdb

I am writing a program in C++ that uses ptrace to trace the system calls of another process. I have a helper function for determining if the child process has a status indicating that it has halted at a entry or exit to a system call:

```
static bool isSysCall(int status) {
    return WSTOPSIG(status) == (SIGTRAP | 0x80);
}
```

When run under gdb, this function return true (as it should) when stepping through the system calls of the child process. However, when I run this program without gdb, this function always returns false, causing my program to be unable to determine when the child process is entering/exiting a system call. This difference in behavior with gdb vs without causes my tracer program to run correctly in gdb but to fail when running without gbd. How can I get this function to return the same thing with/without GDB?

Other information: 
The child process is traced with ptrace by calling

```
ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME);
```

in the child process, and in the parent process I use

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD);
```

to set the 7th bit of the status altered by

```
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```

as described in the [ptrace man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) when there is a system call. The (seemingly problematic) helper function above is just used to check this 7th bit.

Comment: Are you *quite* sure you want to test `WSTOPSIG(status) == (SIGTRAP | 0x80)` rather than `WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP ||  WSTOPSIG(status) == 0x80);`?

Comment: I am not. Would you mind explaining why I might want to do that? I was under the impression that the 7th bit of  `WSTOPSIG(status)` would be used to indicate that the `SIGTRAP` signal was sent as the result of a system call rather than some other signal (e.g. `raise(SIGTRAP)`).

Comment: C and C++ aren't the same language. Choose one. Your code does look like C though.